# Kafka Connect finds 0 brokers[Solved]

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

SOLVED: and I really can not explain what was wrong....it suddenly works with the same configuration, maybe the connection was unstable i really can't say...just happy that my headaches are gone over this issue :)

So, I have this problem with deploying kafka connect on a external machine.
i get this error:

```
connect  | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
connect  | [main] INFO io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Expected 1 brokers but found only 0. Trying to query Kafka for metadata again ...
connect  | [main] ERROR io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Expected 1 brokers but found only 0. Brokers found [].
```

I have used a lot of time in figuring out the issue, and did find some useful things like advertised.listeners and how they work, so i have added INTERNAL and EXTERNAL listeners now i know it is a connection problem somewhere but cannot figure out where.

I have tried using kafkacat on the external machine(tried both windows and ubuntu)

```
kafkacat -b something.b:9092 -L
```

and i do get a response with list of brokers, topics etc.
some of the output:

```
Metadata for all topics (from broker 3: something.a:9092/3):
3 brokers:
  broker 2 at something.b:9092 (controller)
  broker 3 at something.c:9092
  broker 1 at something.a:9092
```

and it of course give same output with all of the 3 brokers

but when i try to spin up kafka connect i get the above mentioned error.
I am really out of ideas..... here is docker-compose code for my connect.

```
connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:7.0.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'something.b:9092'
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "connect"
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-status
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java'
```

I am using kafka version 2.4, maybe an issue there? or what am i missing.....

Comment: "tried using kafkacat on the external machine". Please try instead from the machine where Docker Compose is started. Maybe port 9092 is not open externally (also, the command is now `kcat`, if you upgrade it)

Comment: if the port wasn't open i could not use kcat on the external machine....that is what bugs me :/

Comment: Not true. Run `netstat -tulpn` on the hosts running Kafka. Is port `9092`  actually **listening** externally, or only internally? In other words, did you forget to set `listeners=EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092`, for example? Also, what port is used by the `INTERNAL` listener?

Comment: listeners on the broker are as follows: INTERNAL://something.a:9093
EXTERNAL://something.a:9092

Comment: sorry that was for advertised.listeners, the internal and external are set to INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093
EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092

Comment: That should be okay. Is there a firewall that disallows access?

Comment: Having the same problem.  Still no clue what needs to be done to get it to working.  It worked for several months and then suddenly stopped working giving the same exact error message.